# Android OpenGLES set glOrthof to screen coordinates

Tags: android, opengl-es

I read that OpenGL have origin in bottom-left corner, but the screen for touch have the origin in top-left corner.

So, can I set

```
gl.glOrthof(0.0f, this.width, this.height, 0.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f);
```

to match OpenGL to screen coordinates?
Will I have difficulties with this way?

Comment: Yes you can. It is common to do so. The orthographic projection matrix "flips" the y coordinates of the vertices.

Comment: Thanks, but I never see it on books and tutorial over the net..
Always gl.glOrthof(0.0f, this.width, 0.0f, this.height, 1.0f, -1.0f);